# Set both image and title on UIButton

Tags: swift, ios8, uibutton

I am trying to programmatically set an image on top and a title underneath it in a button, without using background image. I know this question has been asked before and I've tried negative left inset and negative top inset for the title, I've explicitly defined the font, and nothing seems to work. The code above sets the title fine if I comment out setImage, but if I don't the title disappears. What am I missing?

```
    // Add menu button
    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "cheeseburger.png")
    let button = CategoryButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 140)

    button.setImage(buttonImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 40, 0)

    button.setTitle("Cheeseburger", forState: .Normal)
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(110, 0, 0, 0)

    categoryView.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 3):

The image pushes the title far out to the right. Try playing around with left: -200, -300, -400... . This should make the text visible. I have had the same issue and playing with left a bit solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Set button type from custom to system on interface builder! That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I tried numerous ways of doing this. If you are building the interface in a storyboard and know the title & image will never change, you can tweak the image & title insets until it looks right. But for building a button programmatically, or changing the title/image during runtime, I was unable to find a formula that worked consistently.

Eventually, I created a custom button class and over-rode the layoutSubviews function to add the image & title myself.

If you search for such a solution, you will find many examples and I am sure you will find one that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: would be helpful if you posted a few that you found suited your needs